# How to convert an input number 34,6 to decimal form 34.6 in Python

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

How to convert an input number 34,6 to decimal form 34.6 in python? I made simple program in pyqt4 GUI and in Germany the Germans consider "," as "." so how can I convert my input "a" (line Edit) number to decimal ?

```
def test(self): 
    a = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text()) 
    b = int (self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()) 
    Result = math.pow((a+b),2) 
    self.ui.lineEdit_3.setText(str(Result))
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the locale module (here is an answer that should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/1858700/16959)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per in : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-dot-and-comma-into-a-float-number-in-python)

Try this

```
from locale import *
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, '') # set to your default locale; for me this is
# 'English_Canada.1252'. Or you could explicitly specify a locale in which floats
# are formatted the way that you describe, if that's not how your locale works :)
atof('123,456') # 123456.0
# To demonstrate, let's explicitly try a locale in which the comma is a
# decimal point:
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'French_Canada.1252')
atof('123,456') # 123.456
```

Maybe your code could be:

```
from locale import *
def test(self):
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'French_Canada.1252')
    a = atof(self.ui.lineEdit.text()) 
    b = atof(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()) 
    Result = math.pow((a+b),2) 
    self.ui.lineEdit_3.setText(str(Result))
```

Comment: If your question is about the return, it will be float. return of math.pow is a float number